# Como traduzir um ficheiro rdlc usando ficheiros de resx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou a tentar através de um ficheiros rdlc configurar de modo a ir buscar as traduções a um ficheiro resource .resx

```
 public static Stream TranslateReport(Stream reportStream, string partyId)
{
    var reportXml = XDocument.Load(reportStream);

    foreach (var element in reportXml.Descendants(XName.Get("Value", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")))
    {
        var attribute = element.Attribute(XName.Get("LocID", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"));
        var rm = new ResourceManager($"TSG.Reporting.Resources._{partyId}.TransportAuthorizationRequestReport", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var translatedValue = rm.GetString(attribute.Value);
        element.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(translatedValue) ? element.Value : translatedValue;
    }

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    reportXml.Save(ms, SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);
    ms.Position = 0;

    return ms;
}
```

Encontrei soluções que falavam em usa http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition mas esta fonte não está mais a funcionar

Tambem é descrito aqui embora em Inglês
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddff5e7f-2d77-4b64-b66f-9ef3aed041c7/invalid-report-definition-exception-when-creating-report-using-visual-studio-2017?forum=winforms

Comment: basta criar o ficheiro resx, e usar os nomes nomes de chaves nas propriedades ValueLocID para que ao gerar o relatórios os textos sejam substituídos

Comment: @RicardoPontual Fiz isso e não funcionou

Comment: mas não fizeste a implementação do código? precisa usar o método `TranslateReport` para que o relatório seja produzido usando o arquivo de resources, porque esse processo não é automático

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim esta implementado mas algo esta errado nessa implementação

Comment: está um pouco diferente do que me lembro... já fizemos isso mas está mais parecido com esse exemplo, veja se lhe ajuda: [localization-multi-language-of-a-rdlc-report-with-microsoft-reportviewer](https://marcelwouters.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/localization-multi-language-of-a-rdlc-report-with-microsoft-reportviewer/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902037/ssrs-report-definition-is-newer-than-server

Comment: Obrigado    @RicardoPontual desenvolvi a solução para este problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta foi a minha solução para traduzir o report rdlc

```
public static Stream TranslateReport(Stream reportStream, string Code)
    {
        var reportXml = XElement.Load(reportStream);
        reportXml = Translate(reportXml, Code);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        reportXml.Save(ms, SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return ms;
    }





public static XElement Translate(XElement reportStream, string Code)
        {
                XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();
                xmld.Load(reportStream.CreateReader());
                XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmld.NameTable);
                manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition");
                manager.AddNamespace("rd", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner");
                XmlNode root = xmld.DocumentElement;
                XmlNodeList nodeList;
                nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//x:Value[@rd:LocID]", manager);
                var rm = new ResourceManager($"My.Resources._{Code}.FileResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
                    {
                        if (attribute.Name.Split(':')[1] == "LocID")
                        {
                          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Value))
                          {
                             var translatedValue = rm.GetString(attribute.Value);
                             node.InnerText = translatedValue;
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            return XDocument.Load(xmld.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree()).Root;
        }
```